# Getting error exceeded the maximum length of 128 while copying some text files from azure blob to synapse

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am getting the following error upon trying to copy text files from Azure Blob to Synapse:

```
*{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "Failure happened on 'Source' side. 'Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Parse Error: Identifier 'ARCHIVED_AT,ID,DISPENSATION_ID,ETL_RUN_TIMESTAMP' exceeded the maximum length of 128.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=104307,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=104307,State=1,Message=Parse Error: Identifier 'ARCHIVED_AT,ID,DISPENSATION_ID,ETL_RUN_TIMESTAMP' exceeded the maximum length of 128.,},],'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Copy Blob to Synapse",
    "details": []
}*
```

While I have been able to successfully copy most text files from Azure blob to Azure Synapse using ADF pipeline, I am not sure what is going wrong with this one.

Can anyone help me figure what I need to do to resolve this?

Comment: The message looks like it's trying to use the entire header row as a single column name ("Identifier").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a txt file with pipe delimiter and not a csv file.
There were double quotes in multiple columns of my table as well as hidden characters which was causing the issue. It got resolved after I got them replaced at source.

Comment: Maybe you can post the question with more details for us next time. In the end,  you can accept(mark) it as answer . This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Joel Cochran. It seams that the header `ARCHIVED_AT,ID,DISPENSATION_ID,ETL_RUN_TIMESTAMP` is recognized as one column.

I guess your txt file should has four columns like bellow format:

```
ARCHIVED_AT, ID, DISPENSATION_ID, ETL_RUN_TIMESTAMP
data1,1,100,2020-07-02 05:51:32.910
data2,2,102,2020-07-03 05:51:32.910
···
···
```

Please check the row delimiter of you source txt file that if it is `comma(,)` :
[image]

Hope this helps.